# rspec chokes on named path in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, rspec

Re-writing a photography portfolio site, and urls have to follow the format:

```
[site].com/portfolio/[category]/[image]
```

to match current implementation.

[site].com and [site].com/portfolio should resolve to the root. my routes file is below:

```
root :to => 'portfolio#index'

match '/portfolio', :to => 'portfolio#index'

match '/portfolio/*category/*photo', :to => 'portfolio#photo'
match '/portfolio/*category', :to => 'portfolio#photo'
```

I added a link in my header to:

```
%li= link_to "Portfolio", root_path
```

and this works fine, but when I add:

```
%li= link_to "Editorial", portfolio_photo_path
```

my pages resolve fine in-browser, but rspec chokes out on me; even the simplest http success tests that would previously run fine now return:

```
  1) PortfolioController GET 'index' returns http success
 Failure/Error: get 'index'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined local variable or method `portfolio_photo_path' for #<#<Class:0x572d210>:0x5733d68>
 # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_haml__420220390_28357236'
 # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__156489427_30065868'
 # ./spec/controllers/portfolio_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

(when I rake routes, i get the following)

```
$ rake routes
     root  /                                     portfolio#index
portfolio  /portfolio(.:format)                  portfolio#index
           /portfolio/*category/*photo(.:format) portfolio#photo
           /portfolio/*category(.:format)        portfolio#photo
```

Comment: Ok, I'm a dork. I suspect it choked because I'm using routes globbing to pull in variables, and so portfolio_photo_path doesn't actually go anywhere. I was confused about what I need to do, and it's not automagic paths; i need to dynamically create paths another way.

it's interesting that when I use a redirect_to in the controller, though, it breaks again, but that's probably out of scope here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in my comment above; I'd defined variable-globbed routes, and brain-fartedly didn't realize that i'd have to construct the links directly and dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You should add ":as => :portfolio" statement:

```
match '/portfolio', :to => 'portfolio#index', :as => :portfolio
```